# Nullity of a linear transformation does not depend on the chosen basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, then is it true that nullity($T$) = nullity($[T]_\beta$) for any basis $\beta$ of $V$?

A little embarrassing that I'm 20 weeks into studying linear algebra and I've forgotten how to prove this (if I ever knew how). I think this is true, and if it is, I feel like the reasoning is extremely simple, but I can't seem to rigorously spell it out.

Is there a rigorous (and I'm expecting pretty simple) explanation for why this is true?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: try showing $x \in \operatorname{null}(T)$ if and only if $[x]_\beta \in \operatorname{null}[T]_\beta$, and use the fact that vector spaces have the same dimension if and only if they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Bendit's comment:

Let $x \in N(T)$(null space of T) $\iff T(x) = 0$(the value 0) $\iff [T(x)]_{\beta} = [T]_{\beta} [x]_{\beta}=0$ (the zero matrix) $\iff [x]_{\beta} \in N([T]_{\beta})$.

As a vector's representation in a basis in unique, this implies that the vector spaces $N(T)$ and $N([T]_{\beta})$ are isomorphic and hence their dimension are the same(the nullity of $T$ = nullity of $[T]_{\beta}$).

Answer (score 1):

Of course!  But to get a matrix for $T$, you actually need *two* bases, one for $V$ and one for $W$.  Then if you know the two theorems that the rank of a matrix is well-defined, and the rank-nullity theorem, you get that the nullity is equal to $n-\rm{rk}T$, where $\rm{dim}V=n$.  These are two of the in some sense biggest, best, and most basic theorems in the subject.

Every time you change bases, you conjugate by isomorphisms, so the rank, and hence nullity, are preserved.

---

Hmm, still not satisfied with this answer.  The kernel of $T$ is a subspace of $V$.  As such it has a dimension which as we know is an invariant (namely the number of elements in any basis).  And that dimension is called the nullity.

Similar matrices describe the same linear transformation, furthermore.